Printing a numpy variable with and without format gives different values
While working with numpy, I observed something strange. When I print a variable using print() and I format the print usingprint(f'{<variable>:.9f}) gives different values.
For example, 
or

I am not sure why this is happening. the variable lidar_synchronized_timeshamps is first read in as list of strings, then converted to numpy array using np.asarray().astype(np.float128). Any help in understanding whats happening here is really appreciated.

Please [edit] your question to include a [mre]. Additionally, please do not upload images of code/data/errors. - post code and console output as code-formatted text instead.

Are you sure it is stored as 128 bits float? Maybe your platform doesn't support it. Example you provided is exactly what happens, when you have 64 bits float. 1720494130.5012609 gets converted to 1720494130.5012608 as it is the closest possible representation in 64 bits. The same goes for new decimal places you provided, which still have the very same bit representation as  1720494130.5012608.
